# How to auto refresh content in angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to refresh content on angular app interval basis. Its working fine.

But I have a different scenario here.

I want update my content only when I send a request that changed some back end values are changed.

Ex: If user1 using the app(in his browser) and another user2(in his browser) also using the same app.
There is some content which is common for all users and there are able to change the content through a request. If user1 changed some content(through back end request) in the app and automatically it should update user2 apps common content.

I tried to understand the an artical from dev.to, But I really didn't understand how it works for real world applications. Please find the link below.

https://dev.to/eyassh/data-and-page-content-refresh-patterns-in-angular-434i

If an user changed some content in his app running in his local browser the content should update for all the users i.e whoever running the app in his local browser the app should fetch the updated content.

Answers from which include of real time back end are encouraged but solution without real time back end and not be calling apis in intervals is what I am looking into.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in my experience, I used signalR. You need to add to the backend and frontend. Look at signalR to c# and angular.

Comment: have you read about Websockets.. https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1 , they maybe helpful...

Comment: I know real time will help me in this case  but I am searching is there any way to do this job without real time bac kend

Answer (score 0):

You either have to poll the server on a regular basis or keep a web socket connection open to the server to push changes. How to do this depends on your server api.

Comment: Hi @Adrian Brand, Thanks for the answer, But what I am looking is a solution without real time back end or polling server on regular basis.

Comment: It is not possible without communicating with the server and your only two options are web sockets or polling. There is no other solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's one way by which this can be done. But it's not recommended though

sample code

```
numberSubscription: Subscription;

getChangedData(){
const data = Observable.interval(10000).startWith(0); <= this is the time interval in ms at which you want check for change of data in database.
    this.numberSubscription = data.subscribe((number: number) => {
        this.API.getChangedData().subscribe(result =>{
                    console.log('new Result',result)
                });
    });
  }
```

with this use ngOnDestroy in order not to call when you are not using it

```
ngOnDestroy(){
if(this.numberSubscription){
this.numberSubscription.unsubscribe()
}
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead Of Calling Backend Server Again and Again Is A Bad Practice

The Solution Is Signal-R

Go Throw This Link You Will Understand How Signal R Works.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/82b980/introduction-to-signal-r/